# What is the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, spoken-english

I've read an article, but can't understand some of its sentences.

> My wife says she wants more intimacy in our marriage. **I get the physical part, and I’m definitely into it**. But she says she means more than that. I know our relationship needs improvement; I’m just not really a touchy-feely guy. What am I supposed to do?

I don't understand this sentence -> "**I get the physical part, and I'm definitely into it**"

Comment: What don't you understand? The verb **get**?  The preposition **into**?

Comment: I don't understand what 'get' and 'physical' means.

Comment: Does "get the physical part" mean "take exercise"?

Comment: In context, I think we can assume when he says *I get the physical part, and I’m definitely into it*, the guy means he gets (=understands) ***having sex*** as a physical expression of "intimacy" (and he *really likes* sex, so it's good that his wife wants that as well). But presumably he doesn't really understand things like "emotional intimacy" and/or non-erotic tactile contact.

Comment: Physical intimacy is not necessarily restricted to sex, as many a wife will wistfully tell you. It can include hugging, patting, hand holding, gentleness, etc.

Comment: Love relationships in couples have two parts: physical and mental/emotional. (at least for Cartesian dualists and in the West). to get it=to understand.

Answer (score 3):

"*I get it.*" is a common idiom in English that means "*I understand it.*"

"*the physical part*" refers to the part of their relationship that is "*physical*" (as opposed to emotional). This would include sex, kissing, hand-holding, snuggling, and other forms of intimacy that involve physical contact.

"*I'm into it.*" is another idiom that means "*I like it.*" or "*I'm enjoying it.*"

So this sentence could be re-written without the idioms as:

> My wife says she wants more intimacy in our marriage. **I understand
>   physical intimacy, and I definitely enjoy it.** But she says she means
>   more than that. ...